Oracle APEX 19.1 not show other language data from nvarchar2 column
I have nvarchar2 column which have some English language characters and some Urdu language characters it shows perfectly when I query in the database but when it shows on APEX it shows garbage characters instead of Urdu language characters.
In APEX: Institution ¿¿¿¿¿
In database: Institution ادارہ

I suggest that you first check and confirm the character set is supported as explained here. Changing your NLS settings and confirming browser level settings would be the next steps.

Yes supported these are Arabic characters, can you please elaborate what NLS setting should I change for showing these characters on APEX page?

https://oracledevelopertrainingtasks.blogspot.com/2015_05_01_archive.html
